# Accepting unknown entries like passwords

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am playing a little with api.ai to find out how Google Actions work. I tried something funny like *"Initialize self destruction in 5 minutes authorization code 42 pi omega."* like in Si-Fi films.

However I'm failing with the basics. I know regarding the time there is a system entity for the time, but what is about the password? I mean I cannot simply create an entity, because it would be stored which would be a stupid idea to store a password as set of possible values.

Yes this is a very basic question, but I didn't find the right resources or key words to find out how this works. If I could enter a regular expression I would check just for the end of the sentence.

In the end I would like to have the entities *countdown* and *authcode*, I would like to pass this to a backend which creates then the actual outcome like *"The big fireworks will start in 5 minutes"* or *"You are not authorized to do this"*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With API.AI you can use the `@sys.any` entity type. This is a very rough equivalent of a .* regexp (or .+ if you make it required).

So when defining a phrase, you might enter the sample phrase "Initialize self destruction in 5 minutes authorization code foo bar baz". It would pick up the "5 minutes" part as a `@sys.time` parameter, and you'd then select the rest and create a new parameter of type `@sys.any`. When the user spoke, it would fill in the "authcode" part with what they say - it wouldn't try to match "foo bar baz" exactly.

In the end, it might look something like this:

[image: screen shot of api.ai]

Comment: Oh of cause that any type I'll try it

Comment: I have to do this in english even if other languages are supported, that was unexpected.

Comment: @Prisoner - When I searched for your profile image in Google, it returned Luke Skywalker :)